# EF 6.1.3 Foreign key assosiation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using EF6 to generate model from Database .

```
  public partial class FolderFiles
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public virtual Folders FolderID{ get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Folders
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public FoldersTreeDict()
        {
            this.FoldersTreeDict1 = new HashSet<FoldersTreeDict>();
            this.FolderFiles = new HashSet<FolderFiles>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<FolderFiles> FolderFiles { get; set; }
    }
```

After update  on getting  result as list, EF load all date from 
FolderFiles where FolderID=is ID of updated Folder. It's take a lot of time and I **don't need them in this case at all**

Here is the update:

```
       var model = db.Folders;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        var modelItem = model.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == item.ID);
                        if (modelItem != null)
                        {

                            modelItem.Name = "Test";

                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ViewData["EditError"] = e.Message;
                    }
                }
var result = model.ToList();
```

What I'm missing or doing wrong in this update so foreign data is load?

P.S 
In other framework which I worked with on other language there were 2 ways to load foreign data
1) on lading object ( i think it calls lazy load)
2) when we want to get data from association property

Comment: Did you try `db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`? You may need to open a dedicated context to only have this function disabling lazy loading.

Comment: Thx, instead of ContextOptions in EF6 is Configuration property so  'db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false' work for me) If you post answer I'll accept it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false
```

which sets all following selects to *not* load any referenced objects. You may have to load them manually.

Comment: Thx, but i know this and in my case need to force NOT include FolderFiles)

Comment: Sorry, I got your question wrong, will remove my answer.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the discussion above.